# What is the best way to embed a PDF in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, css, pdf

I have a static site and I want to show some PDFs. The PDFs range from 6MB to 55MB. I was wondering what would be the best way to embed PDFs, in terms of loading speed, interface etc.

If there’s a solution that makes it possible for viewers to continue where they left off after they leave the site and come back, that would be nice to have, although I don't think I can code something similar myself, especially since the site is static.

Comment: This is not a specific technical question. Please try to ask a specific question on a single topic so that it can be addressed.

Comment: @Jesse I’m not sure what’s wrong here: OP’s essentially asking “how can I easily display a PDF on a web page”. Seems specific enough for me. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ Is there a specific edit you can suggest? Maybe it’d help me write better questions in the future too. :)

Comment: @AshtonWiersdorf your edits certainly helped, as the original sounded more stream of thought, thus harder to follow.

Answer (score 1):

A nice, lightweight option that requires no extra dependencies is the [`embed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed) element. It’s built into the HTML spec, so you’ll enjoy pretty good support. I’ve used this in a project of mine where I need to display lots of on-the-fly rendered PDFs. (See project [here](https://github.com/ashton314/newton/blob/4a9442c9ba1ffa394726ee70b4cdbdb57096bce7/lib/newton_web/live/question_live/form_component.html.leex#L83) of you’d like an example.)

From what I’ve seen, the `embed` element works pretty well on both desktop and mobile.

Do note that different browsers will display the PDF in slightly different styles. Firefox, for instance, will just download the PDF if the user has PDFs set to auto-download in Settings > Application. I think there’s a library called PDF.js that can give you more consistent results if you need really fine control over the PDF display.